# Creating a cylinder with spiral loops, while preserving vertical loops

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I'm trying to recreate some geometry for a lighthouse model. A particular feature of this goal mesh is that it has spiral loops going around the cylindrical lighthouse. (ignoring the boolean cutout holes in this example)

[image: Goal shape for mesh]

I've tried a few different things, notably trying to use a screw modifer which causes the faces of the cylinder to loose flatness/smoothness.
And I've tried using "poke, and convert to quads" to generate this shape. Both of these attempts cause the mesh to be less smooth, and looses the vertical loops. [image: screw example]

[image: poked faces turned into quads example]

How on earth might this shape be made? Hugely struggling to wrap my head around this mesh. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: That's funny, I was just thinking about shapes like this.. It tapers as it goes up? And how many blue stripes are there?

Comment: 5 stripes for each of the 2 colors.

Comment: and yes it has a very gradual taper, but I figured I could just cheat on that and proportional edit scale down the very top loop after the fact.

Comment: Doing the spirals with a material might be easier.  [Here](https://youtu.be/TmBhgoPoRyk) is a tutorial for doing it procedurally.

Comment: @MartyFouts Hmm. A procedural spiral can be _much_ easier than in that toot. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my technique, such as it is:

- Enable *Add Curves: Extra Objects* add-on in preference if you haven't already.
- Create an Archemedian Spiral and give it 3 turns and a height of 1.  Set Steps to a value that will give you a reasonable smoothness.  I selected 32.

[image: Last Operation Panel showing curve settings]

- In *Object* mode, select the spiral, navigate to the *Object->Convert* submenu and select *Mesh*
- In *Edit* mode, select all and extrude along the Z axis until the extrusion just touches the existing curve:

[image: Extrude until the points touch]

- Select all and *Merge by Distance*
- *Loop Cut and Slide* to add 9 loop cuts.  This will give you the 10 bands you want.
- It's easiest to add materials at this point.  Add a new material.  That will make the object that material.  Add a second new material.  Select every other band and apply the material to those bands.
- In *Object* mode, *Shade Smooth*

All that's left is to trim the top and bottom.  Probably the easiest way to do this is with a knife project.

- In *Object* mode, add a plane.
- Rotate it 90 degrees on the X axis.
- scale it up on the X axis.
- Apply the scale and rotation.
- Move it -2 on the Y axis.
- Select the plane and then the spiral thing.
- In front view, enter *Edit* mode and select Mesh->Knife Project
- Make sure *Cut Through* is set
- Go to Vertex Select mode, invert the selection, and delete vertices.

For a final touch, in object mode, set origin to geometry and set the location to the origin.

[image: final spiral image]

Answer (score 5):

You must be assigning the *Screw* modifier to an unsuitable original mesh? Half the point of using *Screw*, as opposed to twisting a cylinder, is that you can preserve the verticals, and wind up with near-planar quads.

Start with a simple vertical edge, away from its object origin on one axis..

[image]

You can even use further modifiers (*Displace*, or maybe *Simple Deform > Taper*) aimed at a *Vertex Weight Proximity* weighted vertex-group, to do the tapering for you...

[image]

..but you probably want to level the top and bottom of the spiral by hand,  which means applying the *Screw*, anyway, so that would be too involved. Happy to help, though, if you want to go that way.

**EDIT:**

@Marty Fouts made a comment, while I was editing this answer: I agree with him, it would be much easier to do this with a little procedural shader, taking advantage of the default UV of a cylinder, unless you need the spiral in the geometry for brickwork, or somesuch:

[image]

Adjust the scale of the *Wave* texture to vary the number of turns. Adjust the Z-rotation in the *Mapping* node, tilting the stripes across the UV square, marrying them at the jump from U=1 to U=0, and you have a spiral.

That would save you quite a few chores, in modelling.

[image]

Comment: I think this would produce a single spiral, no?  But I believe the OP wants 10 adjacent spirals so they can have alternating stripes, five in one color, five in another.

Comment: Hi, @Marty! What is fixed, is the number of turns. If you want 2 or more  [alternating stripes](https://imgur.com/a/O5QVWsz), just subdivide the edge?

Comment: Indeed! I should have figured that out on my own, given that I do exactly that in my answer.  Ooops.