# Corkscrew shape with a rectangle

Tags: modeling

Trying to create a corkscrew shape but with a rectangle instead of circular bevel shape. Kind of like a Rectangular section cylindrical helical compression [spring](https://images.app.goo.gl/ZrgiZMV6u49djUoAA) or this [cross-section](https://images.app.goo.gl/kNG9Stjcf6p86ayX6). I found this great corkscrew [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIn421hiFrc), but using a rectangle bevel object results in it being tilted by 45 degrees. I manually corrected it with the Tilt tool, but it looks like below. Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/36hvRgY2hGk?t=634) example of the problem. This Blender StackExchange [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235882/creating-a-cylinder-with-spiral-loops-while-preserving-vertical-loops) seems like a promising solution, but has no thickness.

I want to have a spiral with the short rectangle edge leading towards the tip.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assuming you want this:

[image]

you can use geometry nodes for that. It has a very simple node setup:

[image]

[image]

The big advantage of the procedural geometry nodes solution is, that you can change everything "afterwards" to your needs, because it is procedural.

Answer (score 11):

For the simplest version, I guess we shouldn't forget the good ol' *Screw* modifier:

[image]

.. if only to point up how much more [Geometry Nodes offers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296582/35559), now.

Comment: Folks do all kinds of spectacular and complicated stuff with GN. But IMO it shines, in simpler modelling tasks.

Comment: +1 niiiiiice!!!

Comment: Or you just use both: *Geometry Nodes* in the style of the good old *Screw Modifier* https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/272351/145249

Comment: @quellenform  Should have linked out! I'd forgotten all about that Sooo thorough.. great piece of work.

Answer (score 8):

In Edit -> Preferences, enable "Add Curve: Extra Objects" then go to "Add-> Curve -> Curve Spirals -> Archemedian. Give it your desired specifications. The downside to this answer is that once the spiral is added, there's no going back to alter it. You would have to start over for the spiral editing.

[image]

Next, add a plane mesh and convert it to a curve. I renamed the plane as "Rectangle". Set this rectangle as the spirals bevel object. I like to fill in the caps

[image]

Once this is done, maybe move the rectangle off to the side in object mode. Altering this rectangle in edit mode (scale/rotation) should give you freedom to make your corkskrew how you want. Scaling can be done in object mode too.

[image]

By "short rectangle leading towards the tip" and because in your provided image, there is shrinkage towards the tip, it seems you may also want a taper. To add a taper, you can add a bezier curve as the taper object of the spiral. Play with the shape of the bezier curve in edit mode, generally higher towards one end and lower towards the other. I also set the "Taper Radius" to "Add"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have been trying to fix. Your last image shows the issue with this technic. The bottom spiral's bottom edge is parallel to the "ground" but once it spirals once higher up it is no longer parallel.

Comment: @BrooksB With the bottom edge fixed in place, does scaling the height of the spiral fix this for you? That is one way to make the top edge parallel. If you need the height to be fixed, I think if the bevel itself is shaped kind of like a drill bit, this can also rotate the top edge without affecting the height of the spiral